# Vue: second state in Vuex action not firing as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have component in my Blade template that reads off a state `isLoading`.  I never seem to see my loading component though so I decided to log `Date.now()` to see the timing of the Vuex action:

```
toggleSwitch: (context, data) => {
    context.commit('fetchingAPI', true),
    console.log("111", Date.now());

    return axios.post(data.url, data.request)
        .then((response) =>
            context.commit('toggleData', true),
            context.commit('fetchingAPI', false),
            console.log("222", Date.now())
        )
        .catch((error) =>

        );
},
```

My logs are showing the exact same time for both my logs, meaning they are firing at the same time.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you reading it off in your blade template?

Comment: @AlchemistShahed `<v-overlay v-if="this.$store.getters.isAPILoading"></v-overlay>` and that  the `getter` is defined in the store as `  isAPILoading(state) { return state.loadingData;} `

Comment: Nothing seems to look obviously wrong at a glance...maybe its all happening too fast? Also, consider creating a separate action/mutation pair for `fetchingAPI`, I don't believe its good practice to do multiple mutations under one action.